# When using mutex_destroy() How do I free memory: Posix multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

A sample code using `mutex synchronization`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int sharedData=100;

void* criticalSection(void* arg)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  sharedData+=100;
  printf("Shared Data has been modified to %d by thread %d\n",sharedData,pthread_self());
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}




int main()
{
    int rc;
        pthread_t p1,p2;
    rc = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);
    if (rc!=0)printf("Mutex init failed at %d %s ",__LINE__,__func__ );

    pthread_create(&p1,NULL,criticalSection,NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2,NULL,criticalSection,NULL);
    pthread_join(p1,NULL);
    pthread_join(p2,NULL);
    rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    if (rc!=0)printf("Mutex destroy failed at %d %s ",__LINE__,__func__ );

    return 0;
}
```

Documentation says:

`http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0630/6j9vkb8e0/index.html`

```
Destroy
mutex_destroy() destroys the mutex object referenced by mp ; the mutex object 
becomes uninitialized. 

The space used by the destroyed mutex variable is not freed.
It needs to be explicitly reclaimed.
```

So how do we reclaim the space? In the above example, Is there any need to reclaim the space? If yes How?

I suppose if `mutex_t` was created on heap we would have used something like `delete` to reclaim the space.In this case not needed, if I am not wrong.

Can someone show an example where the space reclaim is needed? Or say how to initialize `mutex_t` object on `heap`?

Comment: It is posix's multithread not oracle's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it says it right there in the man page you've provided under **Dynamically Allocated Mutexes** :

```
struct record {
            int field1;
            int field2;
            mutex_t m;
} *r;
r = malloc(sizeof(struct record));
mutex_init(&r->m, USYNC_THREAD, NULL);
/*
  * The fields in this record are accessed concurrently
  * by acquiring the embedded lock.
  */
```

And towards the end:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       thr_join(0, 0, 0);
mutex_destroy(&r->m);     /* first destroy mutex */
free(r);                 /* Then free memory */
```

Is that what you were looking for ?

The remark you've quoted merely means that calling `mutex_destroy` does not exempt you  from calling `free` on a dynamically allocated `mutex_t` struct.

**EDIT** and yes, if you're using the pthread library you should probably look here:

> http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html

Comment: Thanks.. got confused - what exactly does `pthread_destroy()` does

Answer (score 1):

In your example, 'The space used by the destroyed mutex variable' is the global variable `mutex`. So, Its space will be destroyed automatically when the process exit.

`pthread_mutex_t` is a struct type. Just a small block of memory. You can allocate it on the static data section (as your example), or on the heap with a normal `malloc` call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

pthread_mutex_t* pmutex;
int sharedData=100;

void* criticalSection(void* arg)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(pmutex);
  sharedData+=100;
  printf("Shared Data has been modified to %d by thread %d\n",sharedData,pthread_self());
  pthread_mutex_unlock(pmutex);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main()
{
    int rc;
    pthread_t p1,p2;

    pmutex = (pthread_mutex_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

    rc = pthread_mutex_init(pmutex,NULL);
    if (rc!=0)printf("Mutex init failed at %d %s ",__LINE__,__func__ );

    pthread_create(&p1,NULL,criticalSection,NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2,NULL,criticalSection,NULL);
    pthread_join(p1,NULL);
    pthread_join(p2,NULL);
    rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(pmutex);
    if (rc!=0)printf("Mutex destroy failed at %d %s ",__LINE__,__func__ );

    free(pmutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that won't interfere with the pthread_mutex_init call?

Comment: If init doesn't expect the reference to be initialized already.

Comment: @9dan I suppose `pmutext = (pthread_mutex_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));

    rc = pthread_mutex_init(pmutex,NULL);` is the problem

Comment: Are n't `struct record {
            int field1;
            int field2;
            mutex_t m;
} *r;
r = malloc(sizeof(struct record));
mutex_init(&r->m, USYNC_THREAD, NULL);`

Or `pmutext = (pthread_mutex_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));      rc = pthread_mutex_init(pmutex,NULL);`

same kinda initialization?

Comment: @Vlad (sorry about previous mistype) It is passing uninitialized mutex object. Are you by chance confusing uninitialized memory with uninitialized mutex object?

Comment: @GauravK yes, same operation with different APIs (mutex_init, pthread_mutex_init)

Comment: @9dan. No confusion. I understand your comment. What I'm saying is that perhaps pthread_mutex_init doesn't expect to be passed a valid reference (i.e. expects NULL) and therefore always allocates memory. In your case then this allocate memory twice. Whether or not this is problematic is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

> So how do we reclaim the space?

By calling `pthread_mutex_init()` on `mutex` (again).

Comment: You mean to say.. The space is not freed yet.. so we can reuse it, by creating a new `mutex object` there by calling `pthread_mutex_init()` on the same `mutex_t` ?

Comment: Allocating and freeing a variable holding the mutex is one thing, the other is intialialising and destroying the mutex. @GauravK